# Issue in Inserting the image Media URL getting without slash symbol

Tags: magento-1.9, url, media, media-images

**I am using Magento 1.9.1.0.** When iusing insert image in cms page.

Getting `<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg in_en 2016_pro_-22.jpg"}}" alt=""/>` .

it shows without slash symbol.

**Base URL** `www.example.com/` (secure and unsecure)

**Base Media URL** is `{{unsecure_base_url}}media/` (secure and unsecure)

please help me. anyone ??

Comment: I am not sure if this is related but I would start by removing spaces from your filenames, they aren't really tolerated

Comment: @Mayers i dont have spaces in my file name.

Comment: Sorry I thought the whole string was your filename, are you using the media uploader to insert your image?

Comment: yes. i am using the uploader @Mayers

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the issue may be related to google pagespeed. If you have this in your stack try switching it off completely and see if this resolves the issue.

**I've run into this issue with the following stack:**

```
Nginx
 + ngx_pagespeed
HHVM
MySQL
memcached
Varnish
```

I've narrowed it down to ngx_pagespeed so far, however I have yet to isolate the specific rule that is causing this behaviour.

Comment: I have opened an issue on the github.com/pagespeed repo here:

https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/1328

in case anyone is interested in following this issue/discussion.

Comment: inserting the following directive into the nginx conf file seems to resolve the issue:

pagespeed Disallow "/backoffice/";

in my case 'backoffice' is my custom admin URL, for standard Magento installations this would be:

pagespeed Disallow "/admin/";

this will switch pagespeed off for anything in the admin/backend which as an acceptable workaround for us for now, however i'd still like to get to the bottom of what filter or combination of filters is causing this behaviour as i'm sure Magento is not the only platform with this issue.